# Coupling 2 buck converter's output to increase output current

Tags: power-supply, buck, coupling

I'm quite new working with step-back converters, and I have to use them in the project I'm currently working. My board will have 24V/5A source input, and I want to step-down this tension to 12V, 5V and 3.3V.

The main voltage for the board will be 3.3 (the other 2 are specifically for some peripherals). For this I was planning on using LC78_12-1.5 switching regulator.

*Link to the datasheet* (https://gaptec-electronic.com/datenblaetter/LC78_2.0.pdf)

In the datasheet is specified that the maximum output current for the 3.3V step-down converter is 2A. I would like to use 2 of them and link the output, to make sure it will allow to provide more than 2A if necessary.

So the question then. It is possible to attach those converter's output? If so, is the design that I propose in the schematic the way to go? Or I am just committing a crime against all electronics and possibly condemning the project's power supply to break down as soon as I turn the power switch on? In the case I'm correct with my design, which value should R take?

[image: Proposed design for coupling buck converters]

Lastly, I would like you could link me some info about decoupling capacitors, what capacitance and what type of capacitor should I choose.

Comment: Why are you set on using that DCDC? The one you've given the part number to (LC78_12-1.5) is the 12V output one. There are many 3.3V, 2A options out there, choose one of them instead of making it more complicated for more cost. In fact you can get the LC78_03-2.0 same family, but this time 3.3V, 2A. The datasheet also has all the answers to the decoupling capacitors questions you've got.

Comment: Theoretically possible with some external circuitry, but save yourself the hassle and get a proper one for the job as @Puffafish suggests.

Comment: @Puffafish I thought I could do it by selecting same vendor's components, and so far these seemed good ones. The thing is that the amount of "importance" the 3.3V supply source will have depends on the SoM that will end in the board, which we haven't selected yet. So I just wanted to design it in a way that could allow adding a second 3.3V regulator in case it was needed, and I was looking for the ideal schema for it. But so far, the only thing that this solution brings me is headaches, so I think I will move forward your solution. Thank you for the attention!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way would be to use one single converter.

> So the question then. It is possible to attach those converter's
> output? If so, is the design that I propose in the schematic the way
> to go?

Generally it's not good to parallel DC DC controllers output. A DC DC controller consists of a feedback loop to regulate a switching circuit that switches (usually) an inductor. Because of the switching the current output is not consistent over time, and the switching of one DC DC controller can affect the output of the other.

If DC DC controllers are paralleled Inductors are usually best to create enough impedance that the switching (ripple) of one converter circuit can't be 'seen' by the other. To really find this out you would have to know what the DC DC convert circuit is and do some hand calculations or use spice to simulate it. I have had some success in paralleling modules (CUI 7805 equivalents) with inductors before.

With modules, it's up to the manufacturer\designer. You could ask the manufacturer if the DC DC converters can be paralleled , some state that you can't parallel (some of the CUI's) them in the datasheet.